# Converting texture files in blender using Python

Tags: python, texturing

I want to write a simple script that scans all the textures files in a folder containing .dds format files and then save them as .tga.
I want to know how I can:

- open the texture file
- get a reference to the opened texture file
- save_as (not save) .tga files (Targa)
- close the opened texture file

Manually I can do the following to convert the files:

- Open Blender, change to UV Editing mode from default
- Click on Open image and load the desired texture image (which is .dds)
- Click on Image -> save as Image and select Targa format while saving

Essentially I just want the automation of the above mentioned process!

Thank you for help!

Comment: Why blender? Did you tried [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [PythonMagick](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick)?

Comment: @brockmann Because I am using blender to import a custom 3D file format of a game and then export these models as .fbx  to be used in unreal engine 4.
Since the unreal engine 4 doesn't support the .dds texture files used on these models, I need to convert them as well. And I felt it would be better if i converted textures alongside models in blender.

Comment: Ok, can you please share any sample file?

Comment: @brockmann I am not sure why you need sample, all I wanted was some help with python code to automate loading an image in uv editor of blender, and then save_as with different file format. (I mean, I tested it manually in blender but i wanted to automate it)
Anyway, here is the sample:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0WMRZkjfBoCeTJQRmx6OEZRQXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @brockmann I figured it out and posted in answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

```
image = bpy.data.images.load("filepath_to_source")  
image.file_format = "TARGA"  
image.save_render(<filepath_to_destination>)
```

I tried using [`image.save()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save) function before I posted this question, which raised a Runtime Error:

> Image does not have any image data

and I thought I was doing something wrong. Using [`save_render()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save_render) function seem to have fixed it. I still don't know why `save()` didn't/doesn't work.